# Detect marker within circle gmap3, only return last marker from database

Tags: javascript, loops, google-maps-api-3, geometry, bounds

I am trying to detect the marker position in the circle. Marker Latitude and Longitude  taken from the database. I've managed to detect the marker position. But the alerts that come only from the last marker. How do I get alerts appear for each marker/circle?

Screenshot:[screenshoot](http://i541.photobucket.com/albums/gg391/gre_rifky/detect.jpg)

Look for more details, see here: [link](http://fasumsumedang.net/admin/rekomendasi_titik_test.php)

Try drag marker to each circle.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad English :)

code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function init_terminal() {
  var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(-6.832858,107.953184), zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      scaleControl: true
      };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var dragable_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : new google.maps.LatLng(-6.832858,107.953184),
    map : map,
    draggable : true
});
<?php 
        $link=koneksi_db();
        $sql="select f.*,j.*,ka.*,ke.*,i.*, a.meter from fasum f, jenis_fasum j, kategori_fasum ka, kecamatan ke, instansi i, aturan_jarak a WHERE f.id_jenis=j.id_jenis AND j.id_kategori=ka.id_kategori AND f.id_instansi=i.id_instansi AND f.id_kecamatan=ke.id_kecamatan AND j.id_jenis=a.id_jenis AND f.id_jenis=7"; 
        $res=mysql_query($sql,$link); 
            $i=0;
            while($data=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                $i++; 
          ?>
var image = '../icon/<?php echo $data['icon'];?>';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $data['lat'];?>, <?php echo $data['lng'];?>),
  map: map,
  icon: image
});

var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center : new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $data['lat'];?>,<?php echo $data['lng'];?>),
    radius : <?php echo $data['meter'];?>,
    fillColor: "#00ff00",
    fillOpacity : .3,
    strokeOpacity : .4,
    map : map
});
google.maps.event.addListener( dragable_marker, 'dragend', function( e ) {
    if (circle.getBounds(this.center).contains(dragable_marker.getPosition() ) ){
    document.getElementById("latbox").value = null;
    document.getElementById("lngbox").value = null;
    alert("Inside!");
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById("latbox").value = this.getPosition().lat();
    document.getElementById("lngbox").value = this.getPosition().lng();
    }
});
<?php }?>
var kmlOptions = {preserveViewport: 1};
<?php 
        $res2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM poligon");
        while($poli=mysql_fetch_array($res2)){
        ?>
    layersemua = new google.maps.KmlLayer('<?php echo $poli['url'];?>', kmlOptions);
    layersemua.setMap(map,this);
    document.getElementById('lihatsemua').checked = true; 
    <?php }?>
}

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To detect both circles, give them unique names (circle1, circle2) or use a function closure to associate the listener with the circle.